# How to hide table rows with matching data from a mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a table that is fed a bunch of data from a large JSON file. The table generates a new row for each record in the JSON file and in that row, creates a set of  elements that fill with data from the same array from the JSON File.

Here's a picture of the table so far:
[image]

What I'm trying to do now is **let the user click on any category in the table, then collapse every table row with that matching category name** and **replace the then hidden table rows with a single different row that when clicked, will unhide the hidden rows**.

Trouble is, *I don't really know what to do next*. I have an onClick function for each category entry and that gets the category of the row that was clicked, but I think I need to pass the key that was generated for that row? Perhaps I should use it to toggle the hidden attribute for the rows it came from. Is that my best plan here or have I overcomplicated things?

Current mapping method and table row key generation:

```
        Object.values(thing).map((innerThing, innerIndex) => (
            <>
            {/* Tooltip popup for item blurb */}
            ... 
            
            {/* Table rows for each record */}
                <TableRow inputBackgroundColour="#331B18" inputFontColour = "#aaaaaa" 
                key = {thing[0].toString()}>

            {/*<td> tags created*/}
            ...
```

`thing[0]` points to an id number stored in the JSON array for whatever item was clicked

Current onClick function call:

```
onClick={(e) => fireVisibility(e, innerThing[1])
```

`e` is passed when the user clicks on a particular table row, the second parameter, `innerThing[1]` is the category from the row that was clicked. It's an element of a mapped array that's used to create filled `<td>` tags on each table row.

Actual function:

```
const fireVisibility = (e, input) => {
    //input is the matching category of the item provided
    console.log("fireVisibiity was fired!");
    console.log("Input is: "+input);
    console.log(e);
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: How data is stored as an array, @jean182

```
    //get the json data
    const jsonData = require("../Reference Files/Json Files/shops.json");

    //convert data in to an array
    const objInnerValues = Object.values(jsonData.shops)
```

These are above the return block. First element in the JSON data is an object that contains multiple arrays, so it's converted from an object to an array here.

The JSON data is structured like this:

```
{
    "shops" : 
        [
            [
                "Blacksmith/Armoury",
                [
                    [...],
                    [...]
                ],
                "Some other shop",
                [
                    [...],
                    [...]
                ]
            ]
        ]
}
```

Array is generated in the return block through two array map methods:

```
{objInnerValues[shopIndex].map((thing, outerIndex) => (

    // Ternary operator to stop creating rows from element 0
    (outerIndex === 0) ? console.log("outerIndex WAS 0") : (outerIndex %2 
    === 0) ? 
    Object.values(thing).map((innerThing, innerIndex) => (...
```

Comment: Format your json data properly(remove similar columns), then render it.

Comment: Can you show how are you initializing / storing the array that gets populated with the json file.

Comment: @jean182 No problem. Edited the post with the code. The <td> elements are all fed from the `innerThing` array and are displayed as such in the image above. Bit of a wall of code but can post that too if you prefer